# Convert ISO 8601 date format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get an ajax call response in which i get datetime in "2019-02-07T14:00:11.374+0530" format. I want to convert this as Feb-07-2019 14:00.
I try this as following but its showing current date, not ajax response date. How do i convert date coming from ajax response. I get datetime from ajax response by calling "starttime"  
**This my code**

```
function format(driver_data) {
    var a = '';
    var b = '';
    var i;
    var ps = new Date();
    ps = ps.toDateString() + " " + ps.getHours() + ":" + ps.getMinutes();
    console.log(ps)
    for (i = 0; i < driver_data.length; i++) {
        a = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"style="padding-left:0px;">' + '<thead> <tr> <th>Trip Id</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Source</th> <th>Destination</th> <th>Date/Time</th> </tr> </thead>' + '<tbody>';
        b = b + '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + driver_data[i].d_tripid + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + driver_data[i].employeename + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + driver_data[i].srclocation + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + driver_data[i].destlocation + '</td>' +
            '<td>' ps'</td>' +
            '</tr>';
    }
    var final = a + b + '</tbody></table>';
    return final;
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried? Converting date formats is a fairly easy topic to research and there are many many solutions both on this site as well as all over the web

Comment: Yes, it is easy but i dint understand where i did wrong, pls check my code & let me know

Comment: The code as posted is missing a `"` for the string `"apilink"`

Comment: @Pointy i've update my question, pls let me know what did wrong

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Any clue? I'm also trying to use $.fn.dataTable.moment("DD/MM/YYYY"); but its showing error